# Window phone - How to redirect to page xaml form web browser control?

Tags: windows-phone

I have two page xaml contain web browser control to display html string.For example,

page1.xaml : Contain webbrowser control (will display html string to web browser control)

page2.xaml : Contain webbrowser control

Question is : When user click a tag hyperlink in page1.xaml and how to redirect to page2.xaml

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the java script function that call the your native C# function by this you can call the native function from web browser and redirect the page.

so please create the one html file inside the html use the Javascript function that call the native function or notify from there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject Javascript in the HTML that will enumerate all `a` tags and wire up an `onclick` event. That event will call `window.external.Notify` which will in turn raise the `ScriptNotify` event of the `WebBrowser`, with the URL as a parameter.

Here is the code:

```
// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    browser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
    browser.ScriptNotify += browser_ScriptNotify;
    browser.Loaded += browser_Loaded;
}

void browser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Sample HTML code
    string html = @"<html><head></head><body><a href='http://www.google.fr'>Google</a></body></html>";

    // Script that will call raise the ScriptNotify via window.external.Notify
    string notifyJS = @"<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
                            window.onload = function() {
                                var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
                                for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
                                    links[i].onclick = function() {
                                        window.external.Notify(this.href);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        </script>";

    // Inject the Javascript into the head section of the HTML document
    html = html.Replace("<head>", string.Format("<head>{0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, notifyJS));

    browser.NavigateToString(html);
}

void browser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value))
    {
        // Navigate to Page2.xaml
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to pass paramater form a tag ?so that i can naviagte to page2 with paramater ? Example: NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml?id=....", UriKind.Relative));

Comment: You can pass parameters to the `window.external.Notify` method (in the sample code, I pass the URL of the link but you can pass what you want). Then you can retrieve the value in C# with `e.Value`.

Comment: string tt = e.Value.ToString();
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/Page2.xaml?p={0}",tt), UriKind.Relative)); When I get querry string p,I get error Object reference not set to an istance of an object

Answer (score 0):

1. The solution that you are looking for is deeplinking your app to listen to custom URL protocols.
2. First setup your solution to listen to custom URLs. Follow the URI association section in this MSDN            document. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_URIassociations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_URIassociations)
3. Next in your web browser when you display a link make sure it is an absolute URL starting with your own protocol and **NOT** http or https.
4. So, your final url in the web browser must contain something like that: my_protocol://abc.xaml
5. In the AssociationURIMapper class, you catch such URLs and navigate to the desired XAML page.
6. This solution will not only enable your app to open from a web browser but also from other applications on windows phone!